# Cordova nodejs integration for android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I am building a cordova app, and using a couple of nodejs modules in it. When application is deployed to android device, I am getting:

```
I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (1)
```

The issue is caused by modules using `x = require('z')`, which does not work in browser window. On electron platform this issue is resolved by using [nodeIntegration](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/electron/index.html#how-to-support-nodejs-and-electron-apis) . But I can not find any documentation how to enable similar integration on android. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use nodejs modules with Cordova, you cannot embed nodejs within Cordova. It's different for a desktop app via Electron because you can install nodejs on a desktop, unlike a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova runs JavaScript by utilizing a WebView provided by the mobile phone. So you are restricted to the capabilities of the WebView (basically a slimmed down browser) and the native integrations that Cordova provides. You can read more [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/overview/).

Electron on the other hand uses chromium and nodejs to run javascript. So you have access to browser as well as nodejs apis.